# Compile time error: undefined reference to CryptoPP::StringStore::TransferTo2

Tags: c++, gcc, crypto++

I am trying to run a sample program to create a SHA-1 hash using Cryptopp library in C++.
I have installed these packages on my system (running Ubuntu 20.04):

```sh
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev libcrypto++-doc libcrypto++-utils
```

Here's the code of sample program I'm trying to run:

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/sha.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

    std::string msg = "Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.";
    std::string digest;

    SHA1 hash;
    hash.Update((const byte *)msg.data(), msg.size());
    digest.resize(hash.DigestSize());
    hash.Final((byte *)&digest[0]);

    std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Digest: ";
    StringSource(digest, true, new Redirector(encoder));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling the program with given command, I am getting these errors:

```sh
elon@starlink:~/$ g++ -o test test.cpp -lcryptopp -lpthread

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12StringSourceE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_6FilterEEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP17SimpleProxyFilterE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP23CustomSignalPropagationINS_4SinkEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP23CustomSignalPropagationINS_4SinkEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP22CustomFlushPropagationINS_4SinkEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP22CustomFlushPropagationINS_4SinkEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP11UnflushableINS_6FilterEEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP10BufferlessINS_6FilterEEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP4SinkE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP4SinkE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP13AutoSignalingINS_14InputRejectingINS_22BufferedTransformationEEEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP13AutoSignalingINS_14InputRejectingINS_22BufferedTransformationEEEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_22BufferedTransformationEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14InputRejectingINS_22BufferedTransformationEEE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Skip(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZ6zru9.o: in function `CryptoPP::SourceTemplate<CryptoPP::StringStore>::Pump2(unsigned long&, bool)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEE5Pump2ERmb[_ZN8CryptoPP14SourceTemplateINS_11StringStoreEE5Pump2ERmb]+0x5b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringStore::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Crypto++ Version:

```sh
elon@starlink:~/$ grep Library cryptopp/cryptlib.h 
/*!     \mainpage Crypto++ Library 8.5 API Reference
/// \details LibraryVersion can help detect inadvertent mixing and matching of library
. . .
```

g++ Version:

```sh
elon@starlink:~/$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Does anyone know why the program fails to compile?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your codes and it seems that you need to include the header file "cryptopp/filters.h", after that, bugs may be solved.